# Do higher amounts of alcohol (beer) help gastritis?

Tags: pain, digestion, gastroenterology, alcohol, stomach

I was at a party and despite my gastritis symptoms I decided to have a couple of drinks. I drank 1.2l (5.US customary cups). At first (after one or two cups) I felt pain and bloating, but after continuing, I felt extreme relief like I've never had any stomach issues in my life! I could play sports all day that day and didn't get any discomfort while doing it.

Can anyone explain what happened here, shouldn't I have more pain after drinking more alcohol?

Comment: That's interesting. Beer isn't just alcohol. You also consumed more carbs, more gluten, more water, and more carbonation than usual. If I were you, I would pursue this and figure out which of the ingredients might have caused the effect.

Comment: You are rigth, now this lasted for 2 days now the pain is starting to be normal again when I eat... Also, gluten, water, carbonated drinks makes mys tum feeling uncomfortable!

Comment: Knowing if alcoholic beverages, other than beer, have the same effect, can help to differentiate, is it alcohol or something else related to a beverage that helps...Also, maybe the same amount of water or milk could have the same effect...